# Funcunit - why does the speed and reliability of my tests differ depending on whether the test is being run in the active tab in Chrome?

Tags: funcunit

I'm trying out FuncUnit with a simple login/logout script for an app, using Chrome on Windows 7. I've noticed that both the speed and reliability of the test differ depending on if the test is running in the currently selected tab in Chrome.

If the tab isn't selected, the test runs quickly and without error. If the tab is selected, text is typed slowly and sometimes incompletely (so only half the password will be typed before the submit button is clicked), clearly visible elements fail to be found and the test has about a 50% success rate.

Am I missing something here? It's proving less reliable than even QTP unless I deliberately deselect the loaded tab and I'm dubious about any automated test that needs user interaction to pass reliably.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "randomly fails" isn't intentional

Comment: I didn't think so, but I've never come across a UI framework that didn't have it's own quirks around synchronisation - I was thinking that maybe it deliberately slows down if on the active tab on the assumption that people will want to observe their tests.

Comment: Quirks are usually side-effects, not desired (or correct or intentional) behavior. Consider phrasing the question/title in terms of what *is* occurring - which is "it don't work reliably" (although please don't use such vague wording) - instead of asking if such is intentional. If it does happen to be intentional, which I doubt, let an answer say it..

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a Chrome version specific issue